# Modifying the text color and background color of a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I no longer have a question as I figured out how to do it

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactManager.Models.Contacts>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<h2></h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>@Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
}

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Zip)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
    </th>
    <th>
        Modify
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
var lncolor = "white" ;
    var zipcolor = "black";

    switch (item.LastName) {
        case "Whited":
            lncolor = "yellow";
            break;
        default:
            lncolor = "white";
            break;
    }

    if (item.ID % 2 == 0) {
        zipcolor = "red";
    } else {
        zipcolor = "black";
    }
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="@lncolor">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
    </td>
    <td>
        <font color="@txtcolor">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Zip)
        </font>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |

        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Relative part of my Controller

```
private ContactsDBContext db = new ContactsDBContext();

    // GET: Contacts
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var contacts = from c in db.Contact
                       select c;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {
            contacts = contacts.Where(s => s.FirstName.Contains(searchString) || s.LastName.Contains(searchString) || s.Address.Contains(searchString)
                || s.City.Contains(searchString) || s.State.Contains(searchString) || s.Zip.Contains(searchString) || s.Phone.Contains(searchString));
        }
        //return View(db.Contact.ToList());
        return View(contacts);
    }
```

I managed to figured out a way to accomplish what I wanted to do with this. I have updated the code as well to refelct on what I have done. I am not sure it is the most elegant way to accomplish this so if anyone has any better suggestions I am all ears.

Comment: 1. Lots of ways. You can do it in the backend and append a IsEven property to your `ContactManager.Models.Contacts` model that you pass around, or you can do it in the frontend via JS. What is the intended functionality and does it need to be extended to other parts of your code?

2. What is the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Writing any kind of logic in view page is highly depreciated in MVC pattern**. You can do it by using viewmodel. Here is the steps.
First create an appropriate view model for model contact.

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string State{ get; set; }
    public string Zip{ get; set; }
    public string Phone{ get; set; }
    public string LastNameBgcolor{ get; set; }
    public string FontColor{ get; set; }       
}
```

In controller:

```
private ContactsDBContext db = new ContactsDBContext();

// GET: Contacts
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    var contacts = from c in db.Contact
                   select c;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {
        contacts = contacts.Where(s =>            s.FirstName.Contains(searchString) || s.LastName.Contains(searchString) || s.Address.Contains(searchString)
            || s.City.Contains(searchString) || s.State.Contains(searchString) || s.Zip.Contains(searchString) || s.Phone.Contains(searchString));
    }
    //return View(db.Contact.ToList());
     List<ContactViewModel> ContactViewModels= new List<ContactViewModel>();
    foreach(var contact in contacts){
    ContactViewModel cvm= new ContactViewModel();
    cvm.FirstName=contact.FirstName;
    cvm.LastName=contact.LastName;
    if(contact.LastName=="Whited"){
        cvm.LastNameBgcolor="yellow";
    }
    else{
        cvm.LastNameBgcolor="white";
    }
   cvm.Address=contact.Address;
   cvm.City=contact.City;
   cvm.State=contact.State;
   cvm.Zip=contact.Zip;
   cvm.Phone=contact.Phone;
   if (contact.ID % 2 == 0) {
    cvm.FontColor = "red";
   } else {
   cvm.FontColor = "black";
   }

ContactViewModels.Add(cvm);
}
return View(ContactViewModels);
}
```

In view page:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
</td>
<td bgcolor="@model.LastNameBgcolor">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
</td>
<td>
    <font color="@model.FontColor">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Zip)
    </font>
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |

    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
</td>
</tr>
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for